# Where was Rhodey?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

In [Iron Man (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/), when the convoy Tony was in was attacked, where was Rhodey and why didn't he die and/or help during the attack? It looked like there were 3 vehicles in Tony's convoy when they were attacked and everyone except Tony died (assuming this since the bad guys were able to get Tony after he was injured).

Rhodey was going to ride with Tony, but Tony said, "this is the fun-vee. the hum-drum-vee is back there" and did not let him ride along. This, to me, makes it appear as if Rhodey was going to the same location as Tony, so where was he?

**Edited** to include correct dialog

Comment: *Rhodey was going to ride with Tony, but Tony said no*. I think I don't remember this part, when was this?  I watched the first part of the movie and couldn't find it...

Comment: Tony tells Rhodey that this is the "Fun bus" or something like that. Right after the weapons demo. When they find Tony, Rhodey tell Tony, "Next time, I ride with you!"

Comment: Rhodey comes up to the door, and Tony tells him that "this is the fun-vee. the hum-drum-vee is back there"

Comment: Rhodey also says "I'll see you back at the base"

Comment: @phantom42 yes, that's the correct dialog. So where was he?

Comment: You should edit the question with that scene if you could find in youtube, for more clarification...

Comment: Re-watching the scene, I don't get the feeling that Rhodey was trying to get into the vehicle. He looks like he has something to say to him (probably just congratulations), but Tony brushes him off. Tony was probably just going back to base ahead of everyone else, as his part was done.

Comment: @phantom42 just re-watched it, I think you're right, it doesn't look like he was going to ride with him, just tell him "congrats". Staying behind to clean up the equipment is probably where he was. Put it as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the actual dialogue itself certainly sounds like Rhodey is trying to hitch a ride, I don't get that impression from the final version of the scene.

Rhodey comes up to the side of the humvee, where Tony is already set to leave, but he looks like he has something to say to Tony (maybe congratulations?), not like he's ready to leave too.

It's likely that Tony is done with his part at that location, and is riding back to base ahead of everyone else.